# Select a part of a selected item in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I possibly select a part of a row data in MS Sql?

ex. Charmina (Female)

All I want to select is the Female not the whole Charmina (Female)

Comment: what is you rdbms are u using ?

Comment: Im using Microsoft SQL server

Comment: What is the Column Name and does the wanted data always represent `(Female)`or could be other thing ?

Comment: Column name is Contestant. And not always female. It could be Male also. It can be Henry (Male).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
select substring('Charmina (Female)',
       charindex('(','Charmina (Female)')+1,
        LEN('Charmina (Female)')-charindex('(','Charmina (Female)')-1)
```

or

```
select stuff('Charmina (Female)',1,charindex('(','Charmina (Female)')-1,'')
```

Comment: U can use this either select stuff('Charmina (Female)',1,charindex('(','Charmina (Female)')-1,'')

Answer (score 2):

You may Use `SUBSTRING` to get sub sequences of strings

```
SELECT SUBSTRING( your_Raw ,start , length ) AS Alias
FROM Your_Table
```